# How to modify a tikz-cd diagram by changing the placement and length of arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

Consider the following code for a commutative diagram, followed by the output.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\int^a_b", swap] & C\quad(\subseteq S) \arrow[d, "\int^c_d"]\\
B \arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\beta", swap] & D\quad(\subseteq T)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: A commutative diagram]

I'd appreciate help modifying the output in the following ways.

1. The right downward arrow should be moved left so it seems to connect `C` to `D`.
2. The downward arrows should be longer.
3. The integral symbols should be longer.

Comment: Why don't you simply use TikZ instead of `tikz-cd`?

Comment: @DũngVũ: I guess I could. The only reason I use `tikz-cd` is because the package manual contains examples that I can very easily repurpose for my needs. If I can get the same results with `tikz`, it would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

1. put `C` and `(\subseteq S)` in separate cells,
2. change the distances between columns and rows,
3. add `\displaystyle` to the integrals.

to get

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={8mm,between origins},row sep=1.2cm]
A \arrow[rr, leftrightarrow, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\displaystyle\int^a_b", swap]
&& C \arrow[d, "\displaystyle\int^c_d"] &(\subseteq S) \\
B \arrow[rr, leftrightarrow, "\beta", swap] && D &(\subseteq T)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not so skillful in Ti*k*Z, but hope that the following solves your first two questions

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$A$};
\draw (1.5,0) node {$C$};
\draw (0,-1.5) node {$B$};
\draw (1.5,-1.5) node {$D$};
\draw (2.5,0) node {$(\subseteq S)$};
\draw (2.5,-1.5) node {$(\subseteq T)$};
\draw[<->] (0.2,0) -- (1.3,0);
\draw[<->] (0.2,-1.5) -- (1.3,-1.5);
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.3);
\draw[->] (1.5,-0.2) -- (1.5,-1.3);
\begin{scriptsize}
    \draw (0.75,0) node[above] {$\alpha$};
    \draw (0.75,-1.5) node[below] {$\beta$};
    \draw (0,-0.75) node[left] {$\int_b^a$};
    \draw (1.5,-0.75) node[right] {$\int_d^c$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**For question 3:** From my point of view, the integral symbol will look a bit worse if you lengthen the symbol because it doesn't suit the `a`, `b`, etc. However, if you really want to lengthen the symbol, I suggest enlarging the whole symbol:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$A$};
\draw (1.5,0) node {$C$};
\draw (0,-1.5) node {$B$};
\draw (1.5,-1.5) node {$D$};
\draw (2.5,0) node {$(\subseteq S)$};
\draw (2.5,-1.5) node {$(\subseteq T)$};
\draw[<->] (0.2,0) -- (1.3,0);
\draw[<->] (0.2,-1.5) -- (1.3,-1.5);
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.3);
\draw[->] (1.5,-0.2) -- (1.5,-1.3);
\begin{scriptsize}
    \draw (0.75,0) node[above] {$\alpha$};
    \draw (0.75,-1.5) node[below] {$\beta$};
\end{scriptsize}
%\begin{small}
    \draw (0,-0.75) node[left] {$\int_b^a$};
    \draw (1.5,-0.75) node[right] {$\int_d^c$};
%\end{small}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Reposition the arrow using the `shift right` option. (See `tikz-cd` manual.)
2. Extend the downward pointing arrows using the `row sep` option. (See `tikz-cd` manual.)
3. Stretch the integral symbols using the `scalerel` package, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116885).

Additionally,

4. The distance between an arrow and its label can be adjusted using the `outer sep` option, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271155).
5. The arrow tips can be changed using, e.g., `arrow style=tikz, >=Latex`. (See `tikz-cd` manual.)

The revised code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\stretchint#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\stretchto[440]{\displaystyle\int}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = huge, column sep = large, outer sep = 1mm, arrow style=tikz, >=Latex]
A \arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\stretchint{3ex}^a_{\hspace{-1.5mm}b}", swap] & C\quad(\subseteq S) \arrow[d, "\stretchint{3ex}^c_{\hspace{-1.5mm}d}", shift right = .6cm]\\
B \arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\beta", swap] & D\quad(\subseteq T)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Formatted diagram]